# How to create style globally in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have multiple forms which have same kinda views for instance `Text` and `Button`. I do not want to declare same styles in different files wherever these are being used.

Is there any way to declare styles globally and use it in each screens of react native.

I have same style on each `Text` view, right now I am doing this in each files which is not good approach.

```
<Text style={{styles.textStyle}}>
  Never forget to stay in touch with the people that matter to you.
</Text>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 16,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 22, 
    textAlign: "center" 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import {
StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1
},
welcome: {
fontSize: 20,
textAlign: 'center',
margin: 80,
color: 'black'
}
});

module.exports = styles
```

Import The Following Style Where You Wants To Use That Style like

```
import styles from './Styles'
```

And use that styles like

```
<View 
style={styles.container} >
<Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome</Text>
</View>

Edit 
import styles1 from './Styles'

than you can use 
Global And Local Styles Togather With same name like:-

 <View 
style={styles1.container} >
 </View>
 <View>
 style={styles.container}>
 </View>
```

Comment: If I have `const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1
},
welcome: {
fontSize: 20,
textAlign: 'center',
margin: 80,
color: 'black'
}
});` with same `styles` name also in my screen then How can I reference globally styles in same screen ?

Comment: @Williams i would recommend calling them something different, eg styles for global styles and then CLASSNAME_styles or something similar for your local set of styles